# iphone - cannot install application 

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game developed in cocos2d. In my game I have implemented game center. I know game center is not availabile on 3g, but I think game have to install on 3g. No problem if it can't support game center.

When I try to install it on my 3g it is giving me the following error.
I have made gamekit framework link required to "weak", but no gain

`The Info.plist for application at /Users/aqtoor1/Desktop/back up/23/BlocksParty[leaderboard] copy/build/Debug-iphoneos/BlocksParty.app
specifies device capability requirements, which are not met by Shepoo's Iphone`

Comment: what is under ur UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities list in info.plist??

Comment: yes the problem is there i have tick on the game kit :p..

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the gamekit framework optional for the compiler?